# Swift assign value from dictionary to string object

Tags: swift2, nsstring, nsdictionary

I am using swift `dictionary` of `AnyObject` type and reading values for specific key and assigning it to a string object like this,

```
contactObject.lastName = requestDict.objectForKey("lastName") as! String
```

My question is when the key "lastName" is not present into the dictionary at that time my app crashes, so I added the check to avoid the crash, but I want to know how can I get the optional value from the dictionary for key "lastName" as I know swift's feature of getting optional value.

So how can I get rid of adding the check if that key exist into the dictionary then read the value and assign it to string object.

Any help would be much appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not quite sure what you are asking. If you are trying to get the lastName from a dictionary of [String: AnyObject] and convert it to a string, I recommend you do it like this. It will only assign it if it exists.

`if let lastName = requestDict["lastName"] as? String {
    contactObject.lastName = lastName
}`

force unwrapping is always dangerous. Use if let and guard let statements to prevent errors from propagating when unwrapping optionals.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SwiftyJSON library(external framework), it is very clean and you would not need type checks like in ios built-in system.

For SwiftyJSON, all you have to do is

```
contactObject.lastName = requestDict["lastName"].stringValue
```

It will convert the value of key to string itself.
If the dictionary lastname contains nothing, SwiftyJSON will use "", it is very good.

For creating an array, you can use something like :

`array = dictionary["contactObjects"].arrayValue`

To learn more, just google Swifty JSON and open github page.

And all you have to do to use it is to create a podfile and add pod if you can use CocoaPods.